# Combine onload and onresize (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, resize, window

I want to call the function on load as well as on resize.

Is there a better way to rewrite this more compactly?

```
$('.content .right').width($(window).width() - (480));
$(window).resize(function(e) {
    $('.content .right').width($(window).width() - (480));
});
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can bind to the `resize` event alone, and trigger this event automatically upon load:

```javascript
// Bind to the resize event of the window object
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    // Set .right's width to the window width minus 480 pixels
    $(".content .right").width( $(this).width() - 480 );
// Invoke the resize event immediately
}).resize();
```

The last `.resize()` call will run this code upon load.

Comment: `$(window).on('resize', function(){}).trigger('resize');`

Comment: @kzh Did you have problems with `.resize`? This is standard use of the method, as [the documentation states](http://api.jquery.com/resize/): *Bind an event handler to the "resize" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.*

Comment: @JonathanSampson Nope. No problem. Just showing the newer syntax.

Comment: @kzh `.trigger` and `.resize` are both from jQuery 1.0.

Comment: how come .resize() will call it on load?

Comment: You sir, deserve a cookie.

Comment: @Sampson, what's the logic?

Answer (score 78):

I think the best solution is just to bind it also to the load event:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
    $('.content .right').width( $(this).width() - 480 );
});
```

Comment: I agree. It's the cleanest way to go.

Answer (score 18):

It is nice to spot repeating logic and break that out to a function instead:

```
function sizing() {
  $('.content .right').width($(window).width() - 480);
}

$(document).ready(sizing);
$(window).resize(sizing);
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work for both when DOM is ready and when Window is resized.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to combine the best parts of two other answers. First, move repeated code into a function. Second, don't pollute the global namespace.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var adjust_size = function() {
    $('.content .right').width($(window).width() - 480);
  };
  adjust_size();
  $(window).resize(adjust_size);
});
```

I named the function `adjust_size` because I prefer verbs for action-oriented functions.

Comment: This was the only way i could get it working for a script I was using.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way:

```
html:
<body onload="$(window).resize()"> 

javascript:
$(window).resize(function () { 
...
});
```