# Highchart legend overlapping when change window size

Tags: highcharts, position, legend, overlapping

Automatically legend title has style `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, but I need to show all text from legend title. So, I need to set `text-overflow: clip;`.
When user change window size, legend items overlapping each other or
move to outside of chart container.

You can reproduce it here: https://jsfiddle.net/6ybv9kjx/6/
For reproduce you should change window size, when chart initialized.

Also, legend items showing be a certain rule. If all text in legend item doesn't placed in one line with previous item, item move to next line. I need, that legend item can breaking words. Is it possible?

Comment: check this property https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.y

Comment: I need showing legend under chart. I already looked on properties for legend and legend.y doesn't help me.

Comment: The discussion also takes place here: https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/highchart-legend-overlapping-when-change-window-size-t40228/

Answer (score 0):

The `useHtml` is a know [problem](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1249).

For now if you don't really need it just disable it.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/6ybv9kjx/12/)

Comment: I thought, that problem with `useHtml`, but I need use it, because in title I need to use HTML tags

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by redrawing the chart whenever the browser window is resized. That way, the legend elements will be rendered based on the new width of the window.

Assign your chart options to a variable, which you'll then call each time the window is resized.

```
var thisChartOptions = {
    /* your options go here */
};

/* draw chart when the browser window is loaded or resized 
   (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1974797/2596103) */

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    Highcharts.chart('container', thisChartOptions);
}).resize();
```

You can see this working in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/6ybv9kjx/43/

I tried using the `legend.update()` function (see https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Legend#update), but the legend items would overlap each other when the window was made smaller.